# Meteor JQuery and 'slider' function

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to create a slider in my meteor app between 0 and 1 with step 0.001 and I don't want the slider to have a default value and I do not want to show the handle of the slider until the user decides on a value. I am new to Meteor and web development in general so I copied some code and I have been editing it to fit my context.

My JS file looks like this

```
Template.game_task.onCreated(()=>{
    if (!Session.get("sliderValue")){
        Session.setPersistent('sliderValue', -1)
    }

});

Template.game_task.onRendered(()=> {

    /////// the slider stuff //////
    $("#slider").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        step: 0.01,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $('#slider > .ui-slider-handle').show();
            Session.setPersistent('sliderValue',ui.value)
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
            //save value to collection
        }
    });

    $('#slider > .ui-slider-handle').hide();


});
```

Then my HTML file

```
<template name="game_task">
    <div id="slider"></div>
    <span id="min">0</span>
    <span class="quarter">0.25</span>
    <span class="quarter">0.5</span>
    <span class="quarter">0.75</span>
    <span id="max">1</span>
    <input name="guess" id="guess" value="-1" hidden />
</template>
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:
meteor.js?hash=6d285d84547b3dad9717a7c89c664b61b45ea3d8:942 TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function
    at Blaze.TemplateInstance.
```

It seems that I don't have the `.slider(..)` function? Although I have JQuery in my meteor packages (it comes by default).

Comment: slider is part of jquery-ui which is not packaged with Meteor by default afaik. You might try https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/jquery-ui

Comment: @MichelFloyd thanks! this worked! But this slider behaves weirdly at the lower limit. As I go to the 0, I get down to 0.01 and then the value I get is null. So I am never able to pick 0 .. this doesn't happen at the higher end.

Comment: Why not post a different question for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slider is part of jquery-ui which is not packaged with Meteor by default afaik. You might try [mizzao:jquery](http://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/jquery-ui)